# Angular & AutoNumeric - Prevent hovering from removing dynamic value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, currency, currency-formatting

I've used the autonumeric plugin to format values as currencies for various inputs which have dynamic values added into them via angular scope properties, and whenever the inputs are hovered over, the values are removed from the inputs, meaning that calculations between the values of these inputs are ruined and they don't output correctly.

I've tried using the below with an ng-mouseleave directive for each to prevent this from happening, passing in $event to the function, but it does nothing:

```
$scope.basicPayInputHover = function($event) {
    console.log('Hovered');
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.target.value = $event.target.value;
    return false;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/15342/.

Comment: Are you really using the **very** old Angular v1.0.1 version? Otherwise, use the latest AutoNumeric `v4.1.0-beta16` since the stable `v4.0.1`, external changes are now correctly detected even when you do not explicitely use the `aNElement.set()` function.